# HttpClient access url with '@' (at symbol)

Tags: c#, url, dotnet-httpclient, .net-4.5.2

I'm integrating a service that returns a key when I a GET request to a URL that is in the following format:

```
https://username:password@service.com/refresh.key
```

When I access the URL in my browser, it returns the new key as expected, by when I do a GET request using `HttpClient` I get a 401.

```
HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
var response = await _client.GetAsync(@"https://username:password@service.com/refresh.key"); // Returns a 401
```

I think it has something to do with the `'@'` in the URL, but I'm not sure how to fix it, I tried replacing it with `'%40'`, but when I do that I get a `UriFormatException`.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: URIs with `username:password` credentials need to be converted into requests using Basic Authentication: http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-4-basic-authentication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should modify **Authorization header** of HttpClient, can you try the code below;

```
HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
byte[] usernamePasswordBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("user:pass");
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(usernamePasswordBytes));
var response = await _client.GetAsync(@"https://service.com/refresh.key");
```

PS: Such username:pass@domain.com requests are BasicAuthentication request so in fact you try to make basic authentication request.

Hope this works for you

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to provide credentials in url. Instead you can do:

```
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler {Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password")}) {
    using (HttpClient _client = new HttpClient(handler)) {
          var response = await _client.GetAsync(@"https://service.com/refresh.key");
    }
}
```